# How to insert a video with help of MySQL and core PHP

Tags: php, mysql, video, file-upload, upload

I have to insert videos through my form in the database. Can anyone tell me how to insert the videos with the help of MySQL and core PHP?

And I also want to display the video on my site in small section.

Thanks

Comment: upload video to directory and save it's path into db. otherwise at some point your db will crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally video or file we not save in DB, to reduce the load in DB.
We save any file in relavent directory and relavent path save to DB and to display file again we retrive file with help of saved path.

Sample code is follow :

**HTML form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP handler (upload_file.php)**

*Change upload folder to preferred name. Presently saves to **upload/***

```
<?php

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Let me know if any issue occur.

Comment: it working... thanx...

Comment: but if i have to display the video onscreen in a small section then what i have to do

Comment: To display video we use video tags as follows : <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

Comment: will you please look into this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253119/how-to-insert-pdf-and-video-seperately-with-different-table-field-in-php