# How to insert pdf and video separately with different table field in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, video, insert

I have to insert pdf and video with separate table field because currently i am using one filed for both. Here my inserting code

```html
<?php @session_start();
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
include("db.php");
extract($_POST);
$detail=$_FILES['detail']['name'];
$detail=time()."-".$detail;
$path="upload/".$detail;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['detail']['tmp_name'],$path);


$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma", "3gp");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['detail']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["detail"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["detail"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["detail"]["type"] == "video/3gp")
|| ($_FILES["detail"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["detail"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["detail"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["detail"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

&& ($_FILES["detail"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["detail"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["detail"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["detail"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["detail"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["detail"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["detail"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

   if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["detail"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["detail"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
  else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["detail"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["detail"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["detail"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }

 
$query="insert into detail(detail_id,topic_id,detail) values('$detail_id','$topic_id','$detail')";

$q=mysql_query($query);
 if($q)
{
//echo "save successfully";
$_SESSION['msg']="Save Successfully.... Thank you";


}
else
{
//echo "try again..";
$_SESSION['msg']="Try again..";

}
}

?>
```

Now i have to use two different field for both pdf and video.Currently there is one field "detail" for both pdf and video to insert. will anyone please tell me according to my code that how can i do that.

Comment: There is two way 1. you can write common function to handle request. 2. you can write seperate two function and according to request i.e. pdf or video call relavent function.

Comment: will you please tell me proper code as because i have little bit knowledge of php , i am beginner so please... And also i have inserted video with the help of your given code. Please give me code for this question also in your answer

Comment: Is this above written code is working fine for you?

Comment: yes this above code is working fine, from above code i can insert pdf, docs and video together by one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You use same above code for Video upload and following code for pdf uploading :

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $allowedExts = array("pdf");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
       if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
          }
        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }$query="insert into detail(detail_id,topic_id,detail) values('$detail_id','$topic_id','$detail')";

$q=mysql_query($query);
    if($q)
{
//echo "save successfully";
$_SESSION['msg']="Save Successfully.... Thank you";


}
else
{
//echo "try again..";
$_SESSION['msg']="Try again..";

}
}

?>
```

There is not much change only file type validation.

Let me know if you face any other issue.

Comment: its fine but if i have to include pdf/docs field and video field in a single table then what code should be implemented...? Because i want these two field in one single table

Comment: @ManishGaur you just need to add one more coloumn in your table i.e. "file_type" and  insert query should be like this : ` $query="insert into detail(detail_id,topic_id,detail,file_type) values('$detail_id','$topic_id','$detail','$file_type')"; `  . if you need more clarification please let me know.

Comment: can you please update your answer with proper code including file_type Column. It will help me a lot.